# Tex version and overfull boxes

Tags: pdftex, installing, boxes, versions

I'm working on a paper with a collaborator and I've noticed that the number of overfull boxes is different whether I compile the document or he does. It's also not the same whether I compile it from my laptop or from my desktop computer at the university.

My guess is that this is due to the different versions of our tex distributions. For example, on the desktop computer the version of pdftex is 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian), whereas on my laptop it's 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian). We compile with pdflatex.

I suppose the problem is not just about the bad boxes, the whole pdf document produced is different. I am quite bothered by this because I didn't realize until now that our paper could look different depending on where it was last compiled.

What's the most sensible way to deal with this?

Comment: Look in the `.log` files to see if you have different versions of any packages. There should be a list of all the packages loaded near the start of the log file. There is a four year age difference between your two versions of TeXLive - it's not surprising that something has changed in that time.

Comment: Maybe that, more than TeX version, this is due to the difference in versions of some packages.  I think you should update  the older TeX Live versions. Which version does your collaborator use?

Comment: Can you check if you have the same default paper size?

Comment: The tex version is highly unlikely to be the cause of any differences. Add `\listfiles` to the preamble and compare the file list that this inserts at the end of each log.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I added \listfiles in the preamble and was able to compare the file lists. There are indeed many packages that have newer versions on my laptop. Now what? Do I ask the IT guy to update Tex Live on my desktop computer and tell my collaborator to do the same?

Comment: I was using language a bit carelessly  - by "version" I meant the whole TeXLive distribution, not just the version of the TeX executable program. @Seub, the simplest solution is to update the "out of date" installations.  If your IT guys won't do that, as a last resort you could copy the "latest" versions of the files into your working directory on the "out of date" installation - that should pick them up for that project, even though they are not "installed" as the default files used for every run of TeX.

Comment: @alephzero Thank you! If you want to post that as an answer, I think it would do.